# Preradicals generating a radical

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let ${\mathcal A}$ be a locally Noetherian Grothendieck category. For simplicity you may restrict to the category of R-modules for an associative ring. Subject to knowing the Zigeler spectrum of ${\mathcal A}$, it looks like we know its hereditary radicals (*Ryo Kanda, Classifying Serre subcategories via atom spectrum, Adv. in Math. 231 (2012) 1572-1588*). There are bijections between

1. hereditary radicals,
2. Serre subcategories,
3. closed subsets (subclasses?) of the Ziegler spectrum.

Now I would like to describe in a similar way all idempotent preradicals. I would like to group the preradicals by the radical they generate (their supremum?? - sorry I am new to this). To start with, I hope for a constructive description of the preradicals generating the final radical. This is my precise question:

**Question:** Let $X$ be the class of all preradicals on ${\mathcal A}$ such that
$$
\tau (\tau (M)) = \tau (M) \ \mbox{ and } \ 
\tau (M) = 0 \Rightarrow M=0
$$
for all $\tau\in X$, $M\in {\mathcal A}$. What can we say about $X$? Does $X$ admit a constructive description?